# Where has the owner field of struct proc_dir_entry gone? [ Linux Kernel ]

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

According to [the list of API changes in the 2.6 kernel series](http://lwn.net/Articles/2.6-kernel-api/) on LWN the `.owner` field of `struct proc_dir_entry` was removed in the 2.6.30 Kernel.

So here's a couple of questions:

1. Was it really ever necessary or useful to set this field?
2. Has the field just been moved somewhere else, or permanently deleted?

I ask the first question because while [the LKMPG set's this field in many of it's examples](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x810.html#AEN853), [procfs_example.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/Documentation/DocBook/procfs_example.c) from the Kernel Documentation never does.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the bug filed in bugzilla.kernel.org. It has complete description of the issue and possible solution. Bugid is [12454](http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12454)
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Alexy's comments to that bug make it clear that other fixes have made the `->owner` entry unnecessary.

Comment: @caf:  I read the comments on the bug, and what's unclear is if owner needs to be set via the `file_operations` structure if I'm using `try_module_get(THIS_MODULE)` and `module_put(THIS_MODULE)` in the `fops.open` and `fops.close` routines I supply?